# Track how many times my application installer is installed in user computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, windows-installer

I have the following development related queries . Please guide me to achieve this kind of functionality:

1. Just like other software trial package, my trial installer would not get installed second time on same computer. How can this be achieved in windows application c#?
2. How can I track how many times my application installer is installed on a user's computer?

Thanks for your precious time you would have spent to look into.

Comment: What kind of deployment tool do you use? (e.g. 
Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Projects, InstallShield or 
Windows Installer XML Toolset)

Comment: I am using installed Shield Deployment Tool. I want this functionality in my application. Like, When user install my application in his computer that time mail would be sent to admin email id.

Comment: registry entries tell you about the installed products and on second install, you can use these entries to prompt user to purchase full version, or just wont allow him to install

Comment: I assume you don't care how many times it gets installed - you really care how many times it is run. If it can be installed and uninstalled a hundred times but nobody uses it, is that important? It might be more meaningful to create a log of every time someone uses it, date, time and duration.

Comment: Thank you PhilDW for your meaningful reply which is really helpful in my development.